# Custom error message if asynchronous payment can't be initiated

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

In the [Shopware documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/payment#asynchronous-payments) it is stated that:

> in case the payment can't be started (for example because of missing credentials for the shop), this [asynchronous payment response] can also return a fail `status` and / or a `message`.

However, if I respond with a json having `message` property, the value is not respected and I can still see a default error message on a checkout page. Example payload:

`{ "message": "my custom message I would like to show for a client" }`

How could I show a custom error message if asynchronous payment cannot be initiated? Is there anything important I miss in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the documentation also states this:

`Instead of a successful response, you can also provide a failed response with a message (which will be logged)[...]`

So I assume it's not meant to be displayed, but just for logging/debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I hope that your assumption is correct. I made a merge request to clarify and improve this documentation part: https://github.com/shopware/docs/pull/899